# Showing Combobox 2 List on the selection of items on Combobox 1 (C#. NET)

Tags: c#, .net, combobox

I have done the below code to display the list corresponding to selection in the first combo box.
But My second list is not getting loaded on the selection of items in first list :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace WindowsFormsApp1
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }
    
            private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                comboBox2.Items.Clear();
                if (comboBox1.SelectedItem == "weekdays")
                {
                    comboBox2.Items.Add("Sunday");
                    comboBox2.Items.Add("Monday");
                    comboBox2.Items.Add("Tuesday");
    
                }
                else if (comboBox1.SelectedItem == "year")
                {
                    comboBox2.Items.Add("2012");
                    comboBox2.Items.Add("2013");
                    comboBox2.Items.Add("2014");
                }
                comboBox2.Show();
            }
            private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add("weekdays");
                comboBox1.Items.Add("year");
            }
    
            private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                comboBox2.Show();
            }
    
    
        }
    }
```

[image]

WHat I have done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure why do you have two forms, please try following code and see if that works for you.

```
            if (comboBox1.Text == "weekdays")
        {
            comboBox2.Items.Add("Sunday");
            comboBox2.Items.Add("Monday");
            comboBox2.Items.Add("Tuesday");

        }
        else if (comboBox1.Text == "year")
        {
            comboBox2.Items.Add("2012");
            comboBox2.Items.Add("2013");
            comboBox2.Items.Add("2014");
        }
```

Comment: Raulp, i am little confused by Form1 and Form2, will you please explain why do you have two forms? (form1_load and form2_load)?